# Prevent a file from being deleted even after rm -f

Tags: shell-script, osx

I usually stay on StackOverflow but I think on this topic you guys are much more experts here.

So today's exercise is weird, I have to write a `script.sh` and in it do whatever I can to prevent `test.txt` from being deleted but the catch is that the last line **has** to be

```
rm -f test.txt
```

I don't really know much about shell (I usually do c/objective-c)  so I picked up a book, haven't finished it but still have no clue of how to do that.

I thought about permissions, but the script will be given all permission when tested so it's not an option...
(I don't know if it matters but the script will be run on OS X).

Comment: why the downvote :/ ?

Comment: I didn't but you may read [this](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/792/41104).

Comment: Yeah it's true I didnt 'show' any kind of research but this exercise is so `vague` that reading a shell book didn't help much (yet)!

Comment: The downvotes probably come from people who think that the question is too trivial. Using imagination, I think there are many alternatives.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Linux, you could use the immutable flag using `chattr` to achieve read-only on a filesystem level (requires appropriate permissions though). I don't use OS X and do not know if it has something similar, but you could achieve "after script is run, `test.txt` still exist" using:

```
#!/bin/sh
mv test.txt test.bak
trap "mv test.bak test.txt" EXIT

rm -f test.txt
```

This script renames `test.txt` to `test.bak` and renames it back when the script has exited (after `rm -f test.txt`). This is not truly read-only, but unless you `kill -KILL` your script, it should preserve your data at least.

Alternative idea, if you insist having that line in it, why not exit earlier?

```
#!/bin/sh
# do your thing
exit
# my boss insisted to have the 'rm' line below.

rm -f test.txt
```

Alternative that turns `rm` into a function that does nothing:

```
#!/bin/sh
# do your thing
rm() {
    # this function does absolutely nothing
    : # ... but it has to contain something
}

rm -f test.txt
```

Similar to the function method above, but using the deprecated `alias` command to alias `rm` to the `true` built-in that does nothing (but returing a true exit code):

```
#!/bin/sh
# do your thing
alias rm=true

rm -f test.txt
```

Alternative that removes `rm` from the environment (assuming that there is no `rm` built-in):

```
#!/bin/sh
# do your thing
PATH= # now all programs are gone, mwuahaha

# gives error: bash: rm: No such file or directory
rm -f test.txt
```

Another one that changes `$PATH` by using a stub `rm` program (using `/tmp` as search path):

```
#!/bin/sh
# do your thing
>/tmp/rm # create an empty "rm" file
chmod +x /tmp/rm
PATH=/tmp

rm -f test.txt
```

---

For more information about built-ins, run `help <built-in>` for details. For example:

```
true: true
    Return a successful result.

    Exit Status:
    Always succeeds.
```

For other commands, use `man rm` or look in the manual page, `man bash`.

Comment: If she has administrative privileges, she can also change the owner of the file, no?

Comment: @Braiam If the script is run as administrative user, then changing the owner won't really help.

Comment: it doesnt seem to rename it to .txt after the script if finished
EDIT : ok so the first one now works, but im curious if adding exit early would count ! it's smart but maybe too smart I think

Comment: Hey, what a cheater are you! Good one!

Comment: @ItsASecret I made a typo, the rename should have been done to `test.txt`. I really hope you are using this as a guide, and are not copy/pasting? Adjust if you change the current working directory for example.

Comment: yeah I fixed it before you did sorry :p I spotted the typo just after I ran it

Comment: But before I commented I went to check the documentation for trap,
Anyway it works thank you very much !

Comment: You're welcome, what about the alternative? Is it forbidden by your exercise? :-)

Comment: I don't know, but I'm gonna try it !! haha I'll love it if they feel even a little dumb for not preventing that in the rules!

Comment: @ItsASecret I've added more alternatives. I encourage you to use your imagination and come up with your own solution.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Why is the `alias` command deprecated? Do you have any reference? I couldn't find any. Furthermore, `alias` is used in the default configuration on Solaris, FreeBSD, Debian and dozens of other systems and distributions.

Comment: @Marco Aliases are less flexible than shell functions. Quoting the bash manual page: *For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.* From zshmisc: *[..] use of functions rather than aliases is recommended [..]*. Sure, for trivial things as `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` works, but if need more, then shell functions provide much more flexibility.

Comment: Note: recommendation ≠ deprecation; The zsh manual recommends to avoid aliases for *non-interactive* use (you left out that part) and the bash manual narrows the generality using “almost” and uses aliases in it's own source code. Your use of aliases is perfectly acceptable and I see no reason to deprecate its use in favour of shell functions.

Comment: +1 for chattr, make that file immutable

Answer (score 2):

Removing a file requires write permission on the directory containing it.

```
$ chmod -w .
$ rm -f test.txt
rm: cannot remove `test.txt': Permission denied
```

You should probably do this in a temporary directory created for this purpose; you don't want to remove write permission on your home directory, for example, though it's easy enough to recover with `chmod +w .`

Comment: Note: a script with root privileges can still remove this file (this holds at least for Linux and FreeBSD).